# google adwords video campaign using API

Tags: google-ads-api

In my application, I need to create `google AdWords video campaign` using AdWords API.

Is it possible to create using AdWords API?

Please suggest What are the possible method for this?

Advance thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Adwords API doesn't support the creation/management of video campaigns at this point in time. Only the following campaign types are supported for campaign creation through the API:

- Search network with Display Select
- Search network
- Display only
- Shopping

However, you are able to use the reporting functions of video campaigns in the Adwords API. Make sure to [check Google's release notes](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/release-notes/v201809) to be notified when they do add full support for video campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to work with YouTube video campaigns, you will need to use the AdWords Scripts API to work with your video campaigns.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/video-campaigns